# How to get Facebook page posts count on Android using Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am building an app, which lists all posts from a Page(that I manage and post to) and also gets corresponding posts view count. I looked into the documentation and it seems like the page needs a minimum of 30 Likes for insights API to work. Is this correct? Is there a way I can get the view count?

Here is the output from Graph Explorer. I have set the access token to Page Access token.

[image]

I am passing the **Post_ID** to HTTP GET. I can see directly from Facebook that the post has reached N number of people. But the returned data from the API call is empty. Any help?

Comment: For part one, why don't you try and see if it works. For part two, there are ample examples on Facebook's own page. If you are having problems implementing what is written there ([`post_impressions`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights#availmetrics) seems to be what you are after), please post some code for us to review.

Comment: @KenY-N I have updated with more information

Comment: Do you need a `?period=day/week/day_28` at the end of the URL? (I don't have an account handy to verify right now)

Comment: I tried that too. Result is the same.

Comment: Your page does have more than 30 likes? I would expect an error to be returned if not, though. Otherwise I cannot really help, but [what about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365063/is-facebook-insights-using-graph-api-working-right-now)?